# SQL Server date and time concatenation in a third variable

Tags: sql-server-2005

In this code I just want that date and time are separate and I just want to append that in a third variable so I write that code when I am typecast the time variable `@t` in to `datetime` for date it takes garbage value

Can you suggest any solution for that or any other simple way for the problem?

```
DECLARE @d AS time
declare @s as date
declare @t as datetime
declare @l as datetime
declare @q as datetime
set @s=(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111))
set @d='6:00PM'
set @t=cast(@s As datetime)
set @l=CAST(@d as datetime)
set @q=(SELECT DateAdd(D,0,cast(@s As datetime)+CAST(@t as datetime)))
print @q
```

Comment: how about more descriptive variable names: Programming 101.

Comment: Can you explain **in plain English** what you would like to get as a result, in the end?? Not very clear....

Comment: Your question is tagged SQL Server 2005. `date` and `time` data types was introduced in SQL Server 2008. What version of SQL Server do you use? Do you want this to work in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the time as datetime and add it to the date :

```
DECLARE @t AS time
DECLARE @d AS date
DECLARE @dt as datetime

SET @t = '6:00PM'
SET @d = '14 sep 2011'
SET @dt = @d+cast(@t as datetime)

select @d,@t,@dt
```